# launching nodes in a new terminal with roslaunch

Tags: ros, roslaunch, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.I've to print on screen some results obtained with stageros and it doesn't do that in the same window,so it's possible to write a launch file so that it opens one node in a new terminal?Or it can write in the same terminal but I'm missing something?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30754/launching-nodes-in-a-new-terminal-with-roslaunch/) by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-03-28

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ldima](https://answers.ros.org/users/1979/ldima/) on 2012-03-29**:
thank you dimitri,exactly what i was looking for!thank you also miguel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really want to launch it in a new terminal, you can use the following:

```
<node name="foo" pkg="bar" type="bar_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="xterm -e" />
```

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 14

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HassanNadeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/20965/hassannadeem/) on 2015-02-03**:
If you are using Ubuntu and gnome-terminal you could replace "xterm -e" with "gnome-terminal --command" to open in Ubuntu's default terminal.

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-04-22**:
To follow up on this ancient thread: is there a way to keep the terminal open after the node dies? It would nice to be able to read any error messages before it disappears.

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-04-17**:
when i use "xterm -e" or "gnome-terminal --command" it fires error saying "check if executable present and have right permission to execute".
without this options the launch file runs my two node without problem but in same window, and I want to run this nodes in  separate window.

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2018-02-01**:
It worked, thanks :)

**Comment by [stefanvan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33959/stefanvan/) on 2018-03-30**:
It works, thx. :-)

**Comment by [lochlomond](https://answers.ros.org/users/44598/lochlomond/) on 2019-08-10**:
thanks, this really helps.

**Comment by [Ricardo Pinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/54749/ricardo-pinto/) on 2020-05-21**:
"gnome-terminal --command" didn't work for me when my node needs the args.
The node can't find them on gnome-terminal. But xterm does, Thank you.